# Why would an IV characteristic plot for a diode be linear and not exponential?

Tags: diodes, characterization

I was curious about the IV plot for a diode. My professor, and the internet, said it should "skyrocket" AKA be exponential after the knee voltage or forward voltage is met.  So, I took the time to enter in the data into my graphing calculator for both a circuit with just a diode and a circuit with a 50 ohm resistor and a diode.  For both, the IV curve was exponential before the forward voltage and then dropped to just a linear curve afterwards. Can someone explain why and/or show me the circuit that results in an exponential IV curve? The following are images of the Multisim circuits and their IV plots based on the data I entered into the graphing calculator.  The component labeled XMM1 is an ammeter.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try measuring voltage on the other side of the resistor :)

Comment: Scale is everything... Look at the magnitude of your dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

At high currents, the internal resistance of the diode does, indeed, begin to dominate the V-I characteristics of a diode. That being said, my experience is that simulators give very inaccurate behavior for diodes outside of the range of, say, 550 mV and 800 mV. My supposition for why that might be is that exponentiation is an expensive operation to perform, so to keep the running time of a simulation reasonable, they use an approximation to exponentiation that is somewhat accurate around the knee, but is quite inaccurate above, say, 800 mV, or below 550 mV. In reality, the current when the voltage is below 550 mV is not zero, and in reality, the current when the voltage is above 800 mV is, in most cases, beyond the rated absolute maximum current.

Answer (score 1):

In your first graph, 600 mA flows when 30 volts is applied. This means that the diode is fully forward conducting and the 50 Ω resistor dominates (30/0.6 = 50).

In the other graph, you have a ridiculously high current of **600 amps** where the volt drop is 25 volts. This tells us that the dynamic resistance of the diode is dominating and, it has a value of about 42 milliohm.

Everything is behaving exactly as I would expect except, if it were a real circuit and, it survived 600 amps, it would be dissipating 15 kW (unfeasible for a 1N4001).

> *Can someone explain why and/or show me the circuit that results in an
> exponential IV curve?*

Plot the diode-only circuit with a maximum current of 1 amp.

Comment: Yes, many 1N400x spice models include "Rs=0.042" or thereabouts. Simulators should add burning, popping noises.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following circuit, which measures current through a standard 1N4001 diode, and also through a 42mΩ resistor, take a look at the plot of currents as the voltage source is swept from 0V upwards:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fapbiR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

The orange trace is resistor current, and as you can see, the gradient of the diode's trace (blue) is parallel after about \$V_1 = 0.7V\$. To understand why, take a look at the plot of current vs. voltage for a *perfect* silicon diode:

[image]

At about 0.7V, the diode begins conducting very strongly. The gradient of this curve represents conductance (the reciprocal of resistance). It's zero for voltages under 0.7V, representing close to infinite resistance, but when voltage exceeds 0.7V, the gradient increases sharply. In this instance, gradient \$G\$ reaches more than:

$$ G = \frac{\Delta I}{\Delta V} = \frac{200A}{46mV} = 4400℧ $$

That corresponds to resistance R:

$$ R = \frac{1}{G} = \frac{1}{4400} = 230\mu\Omega $$

The reason a *real* diode doesn't follow this same curve is because it has some non-ideal, "parasitic" resistance, which happens to be about 42mΩ for the 1N4001. So, in reality, the 1N4001 behaves like a perfect silicon diode, with the characteristic curve show above, in series with that parasitic resistance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNzMqz.png)</sup>

For small currents, when voltage is under 0.7V, the diode's effective resistance is very high, and dominates the total resistance in the path. When current begins to rise, though, the diode's effective resistance falls (to 230μΩ), and becomes insignificant compared to the 42mΩ, and the 42mΩ dominates instead.

The consequence is that for small currents, which occur prior to 0.7V, gradient of I vs. V is near zero, but that gradient quickly rises to a maximum of \$\frac{1}{42m\Omega}\$ when voltage exceeds 0.7V.

In other words, under 0.7V the total resistance is huge, but above 0.7V total resistance remains close to 42mΩ, and the system behaves almost exactly like a 42mΩ resistor would:

[image]

On a side note, if you wish to reproduce the "perfect", exponential behavior I graphed above, in your own simulator, it is sufficient to reduce the diode's \$R_S\$ parameter, which represents that 42mΩ series resistance, to zero. That's exactly what I did to obtain that graph.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit should produce the curve you are
expecting:

[image]

Here's the curve as produced by a [curve tracer I made a couple of years ago:](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/iv-1-toc)

[image]

The resistor in this circuit "flattens" the curve.

[image]

You end up with a curve like this:

[image]

The resistor reduces the current.  The reduced current reduces the exponential voltage rise.

---

I think part of the problem is that you used relatively few data points over a range that's rather larger than useful.  The [1N4001](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88503/1n4001.pdf) is only rated for 1A.  The current levels shown in your plot would have caused the 1N4001 to pop or burn (or both.)  Once the current goes above 1A, you can't really trust the simulator results.

Comment: Okay. What diode would have the highest current rating that I could test on Multisim?  I used a 30SCLJQ030 which the web said was rated at 30 A, but the graph again reduced to linear at around 400 mV corresponding to 2.5 A.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like, even though it's above the maximum rated current of 1.0 amp for the 1N4001 diode, the parasitic resistance that is approximately 42.5 mOhm for the 1N4001 diode does indeed become relevant for larger currents starting at around 1.8 amps corresponding to 1.0 volts. At that point, the IV curve transitions from exponential to linear because (in contrast to an ideal diode that has zero resistance after the knee voltage is met) a real diode has a resistance greater than zero after the knee voltage is met.  This is irrelevant again because the maximum rated current of a 1N4001 is 1.0 amp and 1.8 > 1.0.

[image]

Taking the suggestion of Simon Fitch in his last paragraph, I changed the parasitic resistance parameter of the 1N4001 to zero and entered in the IV data points using a real ammeter set to 10 micro-ohms (in contrast to an ideal ammeter that has zero resistance).  Here first is a broader view of the IV plot (ranging from 0.5 V to 2.0 V) of this ideal diode and second a narrower, more relevant view of the same IV plot (ranging from (0.5 V to just 0.9 V).

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the top graph, even the IV plot for this ideal diode eventually transitions from exponential to linear which happens to be at the voltage of 1.5 corresponding to around 6.5 kA, wayyy above the maximum current of 0.001 kA for this particular diode! The reason even this IV plot eventually reduces to linear is because of that 10 micro-ohm ammeter that is in series with the ideal diode.  To further drive in the understanding of what's going on, which is why I asked this question in the first place, take a look at the plot of the total resistance as a function of the current in this same circuit (that of the voltage source, the ammeter, and the ideal diode in series).

[image]

As you can see from this graph, the total resistance (shaped like an 'L') eventually reduces to 1E-5 ohms, or 10 micro-ohms, which IS the resistance of the ammeter, although it takes a current of 1 MA (**1 million amps**) to get within 2 micro-ohms of said ammeter resistance. And since 1 million amps is indeed greater than 1 amp, this diode would explode in an instant!!!